# Call function from another file in BrightScript

Tags: roku, brightscript

I have two files in source folder (BrightScript project), file a.brs and file b.brs

There is a function in a.brs file

```
function aa()
    print "Hello World!"
end function
```

and I want to call it from b.brs

```
aa()
```

There is an error

```
Function Call Operator ( ) attempted on non-function. (runtime error &he0)
```

I can not understand this problem.Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Function aa() as Void`, it might be missing the type on the function declaration.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, I missed to import the file's path in my component. So I got similar issue in my code. Once I added this script_file_path in my component file I had got access to those functions

Add these two file paths in your component

```
<script type = "text/brightscript" uri = "pkg:/source/a.brs"/>
<script type = "text/brightscript" uri = "pkg:/source/b.brs"/>
```

then from both the files you can access the other file's functions

Comment: Is there a way to import a brightscript into another one? For instance, how to use functions from C.brs and B.brs in A.brs and so only import A.brs in any xml.